# How to determine if Xcode supports a platform?

Tags: xcode, platform

I working on a test script for cross-compiling a library under Xcode:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                             

PLATFORMS=(iPhoneOS iPhoneSimulator WatchOS WatchSimulator AppleTVOS AppleTVSimulator)
for platform in ${PLATFORMS[@]}
do
    make distclean > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $xcode_supports_platform ]; then
        . ./setenv-apple "$platform"
        make -f GNUmakefile-cross ...
    fi
done
```

Later versions of Xcode supports iPhoneOS, iPhoneSimulator, WatchOS, WatchSimulator, AppleTVOS, and AppleTVSimulator. Earlier versions of Xcode don't support Watch and TV.

I'm having trouble determining the test for ***"$xcode_supports_platform"***. Searching Apple's site has not revealed anything useful, like, say, `xcode-select` to determine the default Xcode. And trying to get help from Xcode just launches Xcode instead of providing supported options and commands: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode --help`.

How can I determine if Xcode supports a platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into the results of

```
xcodebuild -showsdks
```

Which will look something like this

```
OS X SDKs:
    OS X 10.11                      -sdk macosx10.11

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 9.2                         -sdk iphoneos9.2

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 9.2             -sdk iphonesimulator9.2

tvOS SDKs:
    tvOS 9.1                        -sdk appletvos9.1

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - tvOS 9.1            -sdk appletvsimulator9.1

watchOS SDKs:
    watchOS 2.1                     -sdk watchos2.1

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - watchOS 2.1         -sdk watchsimulator2.1
```

The presence or non-presence of a platform should tell you what you want to know.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why I forgot about ***`xcodebuild`***, and why searching did not produce a hit.